# Get values of observable array

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

How can I get the values of all projects with their associated tickets?

```
self.projects = ko.observableArray([
    new Project("title", ["ticket1", "ticket2"]),
    ....
])
```

I want to add all the projects and tickets to another object

```
    var obj = {
        ........
          project: {
            title: "",
            tickets: {
              ticket: "",
              ....
            }
          }
    }
```

Comment: In your case, shouldn't `obj` be an array or `Project`? (Just not an observable one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question properly, you just need to loop through the self.projects and push each item to your target object. Something like this:

```
var obj = {}, i = 0;
ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.items(), function(item) {
  obj[i] = item;
  i++;
});
```